# When calling a method from another class, do variables in that method have to be instantiated in the class calling the method?

Tags: java

Another similar question: 
When calling a method (from separate class) that returns a value which is derived from another class (from within the separate class). Do we need to instantiate the variables of derived class in that calling method?

Comment: Can you be more precise and write the code? The answer depends on what the methods do. In some cases you pass a container, in some cases you can do everything local and return values/references.

Comment: Please provide examples to understand the exact problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling a method in another class, the variables already are instantiated. In order to call said method, you must have either a) constructed a new object i.e

```
Object myObject = new Object();
myObject.myMethod();
```

or b) the method is static, which means it is instantiated already and you can call it as

```
Object.myMethod();
```

in either case, the variables used by the class are instantiated upon construction, and those used locally by the function are allocated once the function is called.